# minishop2 свое поле в административной части

Tags: modx, minishop2

Здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста, как добавить свое поле в административной части minishop2. Я хочу добавить поле там где администратор меняет статус заказа. Что бы текст этого поля отправлялся в письме заказчику. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
controllers/mgr/order.class.php Добавляем в array_map tracknomer
$grid_fields = array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->modx->getOption('ms2_order_grid_fields', null,
'id,customer,num,status,cost,weight,delivery,payment,createdon,updatedon,comment,tracknomer', true)));

model/minishop2/msorderhandler.php
if ($key != 'comment' || $key != 'tracknomer') {
    $value = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', trim($value));
}


/model/minishop2/mysql/msorder.map.inc.php
Добавляем tracknomer в 2 местах


./model/schema/minishop2.mysql.schema.xml
добавляем в 2 местах tracknomer


Добавляем поле в файл orders.window.product.js
/assets/components/minishop2/js/mgr/orders/
```